# Angular 11 finalize is not called when the subject type value emitted is null and not processed in switchmap

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I have a subject which emits a string value and the code is as below: when the components get initialized, the  subjectTypeSubject  is null. But there is another method in a component get subscribed to this observable where i set isLoading to true. Because the finalize is not getting called, the loading is always set to true. How to make it work so it gets completed when the value is null as well.

```
private subjectTypeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
private getPage() {
        this.subjectTypeSubject.pipe(
                    filter((selectedSubjectType) => {
                        console.log('subject type', selectedSubjectType); //first time it comes as null. so it wont go inside switchmap.
                        return selectedSubjectType && selectedSubjectType !== '';
                    }),
                    switchMap((selectedSubjectType) => {
                        return this.customListsService
                            .getCustomListItemsByTypeName()
                    }),
                    map((customItemsData) => {
                        return customItemsData
                    })          
                );
}

private _getPage(pageNumber: number, search: string) {
            this.loading = true;
            this._pageSubscription = this.getPage({
                    pageSize: this._config.pageSize,
                    pageNumber,
                    search
                })
                .pipe(finalize(() => (this.loading = false))) //this is not called
                .subscribe((p) => {
                    this._currentPage = p.pageNumber;
                    this.options = p.options;
                    this._allLoaded = p.isLast;
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `takeWhile()` instead of filter worked for me. If there is any other better solution. please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

BehaviorSubject doesn't complete unless you complete it

Comment: Neither do i. May the expectation is to show some code solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to call complete an observable in a pipe. `take`, `takeWhile` and `takeUntil` are some of them. Calling `.complete` on the BehaviorSubject is also an option.

But you should ask yourself: is this really what you want to achieve here? After completion it's not possible to pass any data to the subscription, even if the initial BehaviorSubject emits a new value.

One thing that this strange about your code: it should not work at all. In `getPage()` you are creating a new observable (by piping the BehaviorSubject), but you are not returning it. Therefore it should return `undefined`. It‘s also a little bit odd that you are using `pipe` in a function call. You should either declare the pipe during initialization or directly subscribe to a newly created observable.